# setting the R engine hangs without error

Tags: java, r

I'm using rJava in my java project to plot some graphs. I do that using r Scripts which are called within the java code.

Further explaining, I created a java class and within that wrote separate methods to call the r scripts as and when it needs. The function is like this;

```
public void graphing1() throws IOException {
    String newargs1[] = {"--no-save"};
    Rengine r1 = new Rengine(newargs1, false, null);
    r1.eval("source('test2.R')"); 
    r1.end();
}

public void fitness() throws IOException {
    String newargs1[] = {"--no-save"};
    Rengine r3 = new Rengine(newargs1, false, null);
    r3.eval("source('A.R')"); 
    r3.eval("source('B.R')"); 
    r3.end();
}
```

Both of the above methods are in java class MyClass.

From another class in the same project for which i created a gui, i accessed the fitness() function and it worked fine. but when I try to call the graphing1() function it did not work. (both were called through the gui) 
The programme hangs at ;

```
Rengine r1 = new Rengine(newargs1, false, null);
```

without any notification. In both instances I called the function as follows:

1st instance:

```
MyClass test=new MyClass();
    test.fitness() ;
```

2nd instance:

```
MyClass test1 = new MyClass();
        test1.graphing1();
```

I'm using netbeans. I'm still a learner and do not have much knowledge in both R and java.

pls help me to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: fixed it by adding/modifying the setting up of rengine as follows:     String newargs1[] = {"--no-save"};

        Rengine r1 = Rengine.getMainEngine();
       if (r1 == null) {
           r1 = new Rengine(newargs1, false, null);
       }

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by adding/modifying the setting up of rengine as follows:

```
String newargs1[] = {"--no-save"}; 
Rengine r1 = Rengine.getMainEngine(); 
if (r1 == null) 
{ r1 = new Rengine(newargs1, false, null); 
}
```

Did the same at all instances that Rengine was set up (including for r3).